# opencart htaccess too many redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to set http to https. However, when I access to https, it goes to too many redirect.

Below is my rules:-

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]


RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
#NEW REWRITE RULES
RewriteRule    ^contact/?$    index.php?route=information/contact  [L]  #Contact Page
#END NEW REWRITE RULES
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The same coding works fine in my cPanel website. But come hows it just does not work when I move to another server (VPS).

When I access via `http://www.example.com` it will redirect to `https://www.example.com`, but then next error will be too many redirect.

If I commented

```
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

then it will work normally in **HTTPS**, totally no idea...

I can't understand why it meets the infinite loop condition.
http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=e7301d40-f5c3-5476-aa44-de304a066bf6

**Apache version: 2.4.23-0ubuntu1**

**PHP: 7.0.20**

Comment: Apache version: 2.4.23-0ubuntu1

PHP: 7.0.20

Comment: still the same ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dg.sakunsilk.com/$1 [R,L]`
i close incognito mode and open it with new session in incognito, still too many redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)? [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[\w-]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]
```

Replace `%{REQUEST_URI}` by `%{THE_REQUEST}` as `REQUEST_URI` gets changed to `index.php` in your last rule thus triggering your first rule again.

If you're using a proxy then you will need to add this condition as well:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =off
```